# A Solution for Block/File Encryption that is Corruption Resilient?

Tags: encryption, windows, disk-encryption, file-encryption, luks

**Question:**  What encryption features/(configuration options) are implemented that mitigate issues with device/block corruption?

For example, if the external hard-drive gets dropped, the damaged portion of the data shouldn't cause ***cascading faults*** through all of the different encrypted data-sets on the drive.

What software solutions, (or configuration options), allow for write redundancy, or some other mechanism to un-encrypt the rest of a device when a device/block corruption issue is present?

Can these be made "Resilient"?

1. EncFS (which configuration option?)
2. TrueCrypt/VeraCrypt
3. LibreCrypt
4. Luks (for Windows?)
5. ecryptfs (Linux only)

**Notes:**
There was recently and audit, (defuse [link](https://defuse.ca/audits/encfs.htm)), on EncFS which highlighted risks that are hoped to be fixed in EncFS version 2.

Comment: You simply need error correction codes, to address storage level faults. Not all encryption tools have them built in. Some drives do.

Comment: You can setup your encryption over a RAID array. But that's not really an infosec question...

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  I am looking for a software solution, so that it can be used on USB devices, etc.  I am wondering if there is any write redundancy, or other cryptographic features that won't render the whole block/device not accessible when there is a storage/device fault.  -- Will clarify the question.